# How to check undefined key in perl OO code?

Tags: perl

I have `use strict;use warnings;` in my perl script;

But this error cannot be found:

```
sub new {
     #....
     my $self={};
     $self->{databas}="..."; # 'e' is missing
     #....
}

sub foo {
    my $self=shift;
    print $self->{database}; # undef
 }
```

I have spend hours to found out that database in mispelled in `sub new`.

`use strict;use warnings;` didnt help.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restrict/lock hashes with [Hash::Util](http://p3rl.org/Hash::Util#Restricted-hashes).

---

Alternatively, use [Moose](http://moose.perl.org) to describe your classes, making a misspelled attribute a run-time error.

```
package MyClass;
use Moose;
has 'database' => (isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', default => 'quux');

sub foo {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->database; # returns quux
    $self->databas;  # Can't locate object method "databas" via package…
```

Answer (score 1):

use `defined`, or `//` operator (if you have perl 5.10/later)

```
print "not defined" if !defined $a; # check if $a is undef 

print $a // 'undefed!';             # print a if availiable, "undefed!" otherwise
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-Defined-Or

Comment: Thanks. But this is too much. I have to put defined before every var. Is there any module to help auto-check?

Comment: I guess not, your ` $self->{databas}` syntax is how you create new key. If it error on this, how do the modules create that key on the first place?

Comment: You could check that you have all the expected hash values at the start of the sub, and stop if one is missing. You can check many at once, you don't need one line per variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use getters and setters instead of hash keys, or switch to Moose.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think you would have spotted it if you saw the hash dumped out? Like this:

```
$self = bless( {
                 'anotherfield' => 'something else',
                 'databas' => '...',
                 'afield' => 'something'
               }, 'MyClass' );
```

If you were wondering "How come 'database' *isn't set?!?!*" and you dumped this out, do you think that would help? "Oh it assigned 'databas' not 'database'!"

Then [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) is the minimal Perl debugging tool

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
# Why isn't database assigned?!?!
say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $self ], [ '$self' ] );
```

Of course, the most convenient form of [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) tools is [`Smart:Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Smart%3a%3aComments).

```
use Smart::Comments;
...
### $self
```

Which outputs:

```
### $self: bless( {
###                 afield => 'something',
###                 anotherfield => 'something else',
###                 databas => '...'
###               }, 'MyClass' )
```

It's not as *preventative* a tool as *Moose* but it will save *hours*, though. I think it even helps you learn Perl tricks and practices as you spill out the guts of CPAN objects. When you know the underlying structure, you have something to search for in CPAN modules.

Like I said, it solves the problem of *hours* tracking down bugs (often enough).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the core module [Class::Struct](https://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aStruct).

```
package MyObj;

use Class::Struct;

struct(
    databas => '$',
    # ...
);

1;

package main;

# create object
my $obj = MyObj->new(databas => 'MyDB');

# later
print $obj->database;
```

Running this results in the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "database" via package "MyObj" at ... .
```